# Decimal quantity in opencart 1.5.1

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

The quantity using in my store is like 1.200 kg, but now the opencart calculating the quantity as 1,2, etc., (Whole numbers).

I've done the below updations

```
system/library/cart.php
 (int)$qty -> (float)$qty
 admin/model/catalog/product.php
 (int)$data['quantity'] -> (float)$data['quantity']
 (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] -> (float)$product_option_value['quantity']
 (int)$product_discount['quantity'] -> (float)$product_discount['quantity']
 admin/model/sale/order.php
 (int)$order_product['quantity'] -> (float)$order_product['quantity']
 (int)($download['remaining'] * $product['quantity'] 
      -> (float)($download['remaining'] * (float)$product['quantity']
 (int)$return_product['quantity'] -> (float)$return_product['quantity']
 (int)$product['quantity'] -> (float)$product['quantity']
 catalog/model/checkout/order.php
 (int)$product['quantity'] -> (float)$product['quantity']
 (int)($download['remaining'] * $product['quantity'] 
      -> (float)($download['remaining'] * (float)$product['quantity']
 (int)$order_product['quantity'] -> (float)$order_product['quantity']


ALTER TABLE `product` CHANGE `quantity` `quantity` DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE `product` CHANGE `minimum` `minimum` DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) NOT NULL ;
ALTER TABLE `order_product` CHANGE `quantity` `quantity` DECIMAL( 6, 2 ) NOT NULL ;
```

But the rate calculated in the cart is showing the price value for the rounded off quantity.

Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: The quantity using in my store is like 1.200 kg, but now the opencart calculating the quantity as 1,2, etc., (Whole numbers).

Comment: Did You debug the whole checkout process to identify the place where the float quantity is again rounded to integer? If not, please, do so.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use grams instead of kilograms and make necessary price changes, so that you don't need to modify the default opencart code. Also make sure that you're using grams everywhere.